# Issue with sql code, only returning one row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, sql-order-by

I'm having trouble with this sql query...

```
SELECT c.country_code, co.country_name, COUNT(c.city_name)
FROM Country co JOIN City c USING (country_code)
ORDER BY COUNT(c.city_name)
GROUP BY c.country_code
```

This is returning an error near the group by statement. I am just not getting where my query is wrong. I have also tested where I just enter the select and from statement, to try and get all the countries with the total amount of cities each has, but it still returns only canada and it says it has 44 cities, which is obviously wrong. Can someone help explain why the query is wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE Country ( 
        country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country abbreviation */
        country_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country name*/
        gdp INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, /*-- groSEELss domestic product*/
        inflation DOUBLE NOT NULL, /*-- inflation rate */
        PRIMARY KEY (country_code)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('US', 'United States', 37000, 3.8);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('MEX', 'Mexico', 27000, 2.8);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('CAN', 'Canada', 34000, 3.6);
    
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('CHN', 'China', 70000, 0.3);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('GER', 'Germany', 67000, 0.9);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('SPA', 'Spain', 37000, 2.5);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('FRA', 'France', 43000, 1.2);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('ITA', 'Italy', 50000, 1.5);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('IND', 'India', 56000, 3.1);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('MON', 'Mongolia', 32000, 2.5);
    INSERT INTO Country VALUES ('RUS', 'Russia', 74000, 3.5);
    
    
    /* Table describes the provinces each country has */
    
    
    CREATE TABLE Province (
        province_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* province name */
        country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  /* country abbreviation */
        area INT UNSIGNED, /* total province area in km^2 */
        PRIMARY KEY (province_name, country_code),
        FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Country (country_code)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Washington', 'US', 400000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Oregon', 'US', 300000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('California', 'US', 200000);
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Jalisco', 'MEX', 230000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 130000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Yucatan', 'MEX', 430000);
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('British Columbia', 'CAN', 530000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Ontario', 'CAN', 50000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Alberta', 'CAN', 48000);
    
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Guizhou', 'CHN', 428000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Shandong', 'CHN', 58000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Hunan', 'CHN', 89000);
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Bavaria', 'GER', 708000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Saxony', 'GER', 41000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Hessen', 'GER', 480000);
    
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Catalonia', 'SPA', 485000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Galicia', 'SPA', 85000);
    INSERT INTO Province VALUES ('Castilla La Mancha', 'SPA', 67000);
    
    
    
    
    /* Table describes the cities in the different provinces */
    
    CREATE TABLE City (
        city_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /*name of city */
        province_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* name of province */
        country_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, /* country abbreviation */
        population INT UNSIGNED, /* total population */
        PRIMARY KEY (city_name, province_name, country_code),
        FOREIGN KEY (province_name) REFERENCES Province (province_name),
        FOREIGN KEY (country_code) REFERENCES Province (country_code)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Seattle', 'Washington', 'US', 23030);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Redmond', 'Washington', 'US', 2400);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Kirkland', 'Washington', 'US', 22350);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Portland', 'Oregon', 'US', 33040);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Sunriver', 'Oregon', 'US', 4300);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Bend', 'Oregon', 'US', 54300);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('San Francisco', 'California', 'US', 6300);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('San Diego', 'California', 'US', 2300);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Los Angelos', 'California', 'US', 7300);
    
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Puerto Vallarta', 'Jalisco', 'MEX', 4800);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Zapopan', 'Jalisco', 'MEX', 1900);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Monterrey', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 9200);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Santa Catarina', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 470);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Guadalupe', 'Nuevo Leon', 'MEX', 500);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Merida', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 2000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Valladolid', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 480);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Izamal', 'Yucatan', 'MEX', 200);
    
   
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Victoria', 'British Columbia', 'CAN', 2200);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('London', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 2300);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Toronto', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 3500);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Ottawa', 'Ontario', 'CAN', 8000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Calgary', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 3040);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Red Deer', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 5700);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Edmonton', 'Alberta', 'CAN', 300);
    
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Guiyang', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 40000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Anshun', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 23000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Zunyi', 'Guizhou', 'CHN', 10000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Qingdao', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 100000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Jinan', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 9000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Yantai', 'Shandong', 'CHN', 70000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Changsha', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 100000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Yueyang', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 5000);
    INSERT INTO City VALUES ('Changde', 'Hunan', 'CHN', 57700);
```